# Github Action environment secret can't be access

Tags: deployment, github-actions, workflow

I want to do deployments with Github Action into 2 different AKS Cluster. I have set up repository level secrets and a `prod` environment level secret.

I have nested workflows:

```
name: Production Deployment

on:
    workflow_dispatch: 
    push:
        tags:
            - prod/v.**

jobs:
    deploy-prod-environment:
        // HERE I CAN'T USE THE environment:prod, error from github
        name: Production deployment
        uses: XXXX/.github/workflows/step_deployment.yaml@master
        with:
            environment: prod
            kubernetes_namespace: XXX
        secrets:
            REGISTRY_GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}
            CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}
            SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
            TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}
            CLUSTER_NAME: ${{ secrets.CLUSTER_NAME }}
            RESOURCE_GROUP: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}
            GITHUB_ACTOR: ${{ github.actor }}
            REGISTRY: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY }}
```

This is then the step_deployment.yaml

```
name: Deploy to a specific environment

on:
    workflow_call:
        inputs:
            environment:
                type: string
                required: true
            ...
        secrets:
            REGISTRY_GITHUB_TOKEN:
                required: true
            CLIENT_ID:
                required: true
            CLIENT_SECRET:
                required: true
            SUBSCRIPTION_ID:
                required: true
            TENANT_ID:
                required: true
            GITHUB_ACTOR:
                required: true
            CLUSTER_NAME:
                required: true
            RESOURCE_GROUP:
                required: true
            REGISTRY:
                required: true
jobs:                   
....
building the docker images
....

    release:
        name: Release
        uses: XXX/.github/workflows/step_release.yaml@master
        needs: [docker-image-builds ]
        with:
            environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
            sha: ${{ github.sha }}
            kubernetes_namespace: ${{ inputs.kubernetes_namespace }}
        secrets:
            GITHUB_ACTOR: ${{ github.actor }}
            CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}
            CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}
            SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
            TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}
            CLUSTER_NAME: ${{ secrets.CLUSTER_NAME }}
            RESOURCE_GROUP: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}
```

and this is the step_release.yaml

```
name: Release

on:
    workflow_call:
        inputs:
            environment:
                required: true
                type: string
            sha:
                required: true
                type: string
            kubernetes_namespace:
                required: true
                type: string
        secrets:
            CLIENT_ID:
                required: true
            CLIENT_SECRET:
                required: true
            SUBSCRIPTION_ID:
                required: true
            TENANT_ID:
                required: true
            GITHUB_ACTOR:
                required: true
            CLUSTER_NAME:
                required: true
            RESOURCE_GROUP:
                required: true

jobs:
    log-in-to-azure-and-deploy:
        name: Login into Azure cluster and set the right context
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
        steps:
            -   uses: actions/checkout@v3
            -   name: Azure login
                id: login
                uses: azure/login@v1.4.3
                with:
                    creds: '{"clientId":"${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}","clientSecret":"${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}","subscriptionId":"${{ secrets.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}","tenantId":"${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}"}'
           ........
```

In the step_release.yaml I was able to specify on job level the environment and the protection works - it asks for a confirmation before deployment, this is perfect - but I can't get the secrets for PROD env, github says always, that I have no access to it inside the steps and in the main workflow it's always the repository level env vars.

How can I access there already the prod environment secrets?

Comment: [`secrets: inherit`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow) also doesn't work?

Comment: BTW, is `GITHUB_ACTOR: ${{ github.actor }}` working fine as a secret without being encoded as BASE64?